# Cancelling another task while WhenAll throws TaskWasCancelled

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand what is the best possible way of dealing with a problem that this is and also how do I over come `TaskWasCancelledException` where cancelling of task seems a genuine use case.

So, scenario is: I have a Huge list of names, that I want to match with 3 different `Regex`. If we find a match in any one of the `Regex`, we add the name into a `ConcurrentBag` and stop matching it with other `Regex`es. So my basic algo for this is

- Iterate through all names in parallel
- Start three different tasks with Regex.IsMatch
- Each of these three tasks have `CancellationToken`
- As soon as there is a match, add the item into Bag and **Cancel** other tasks.
- Wait for all tasks to finish.

My problem is in last step, where we are waiting for tasks to finish, `WaitAll` throws `TaskWasCancelledException`. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my approach and what else can be a better way of dealing with such scenario.

Also, i have to check for `task != null` which again I don't understand that why and when some of the tasks are being set to `null`.

```
Parallel.ForEach(accounts, p =>
    {
        var can1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var can2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var can3 = new CancellationTokenSource();

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (reg1.IsMatch(p.DisplayName))
            {
                bag.Add(p);
                can2.Cancel();
                can3.Cancel();
            }
        }, can1.Token));

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (reg2.IsMatch(p.DisplayName))
            {
                bag.Add(p);
                can1.Cancel();
                can3.Cancel();
            }
        }, can2.Token));

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (reg3.IsMatch(p.DisplayName))
            {
                bag.Add(p);
                can1.Cancel();
                can2.Cancel();
            }
        }, can3.Token));
    }
);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray());
```

Comment: awaiting a cancelled task throws a TaskCancelledException. That's by design. If you expect one of the task to be cancelled, just catch the exception and move on

Comment: yea i understand its by design and can be held by catching exceptions but am looking for a cleaner way to do it. It looks like a simple scenario, wanting to see how others deal with it really

Comment: There is no other way, when awaiting a cancelled task it will throw a `TaskCancelledException`. Thats the way it works. If you don't like it then don't use `await`, use only `Task` and a good old `switch` with the state the task finished with, but I wouldn't consider that "cleaner".

Comment: As for your code itself, the biggest flaw is that you're using tasks to run CPU-intensive operations when you already have a `Parallel.ForEach`. Just remove the tasks, execute your regular expressions sequentially (with simple if/else statements), and let `Parallel.ForEach` take care of parallelizing the operations

Comment: if i remove tasks, all regex match happens sequentially so if the match is to be found in 3rd regex time for first to is essentially wasted, let me get you times

Comment: @KevinGosse thanks for the insight, i just checked time difference is nothing in two cases, can you please give me a little details as to why running a cpu intensive task sequentially takes similar time to if that was done in parallel.

My understanding was that if there are multiple cores, you can run multiple cpu intensive tasks in parallel to reduce processing times.

Comment: That's because your CPU can only run that many tasks in parallel. If you have for instance a 4 cores CPU, then only 4 threads can run together at a given time. Which means that, as long as you're using at least 4 threads, creating additional tasks won't increase the performance (and will in fact decrease it because of the additional overhead). `Parallel.ForEach` is smart enough to start as many threads as your CPU can handle, so you don't need to create additional tasks. Note that this is only true for CPU-bound operations. For IO-bound operations this is a whole different story

Comment: my understanding was, that all new tasks within one parallel execution get priority and hence they will be executed in parallel, and thus tasks will be many but short lived, but it seems, all foreach occupies all cores first and leaving no free cpu for threads within one foreach iteration

Comment: It's like having 3 equations on a sheet of paper, and trying to find out which of the three is correct. If you have 2 friends, it's faster if you split the work in 3 and every single of you checks one equation. Now say that you have 3 sheets of paper (with three equation each). Whether each of you take one sheet, or whether you continue splitting the equations on a single sheet, you will go exactly as fast.

Comment: makes sense, strill trying to get my head around multi-threadin, parallel processing and async... thanks for your help

any idea why some tasks are null while we are waiting for them, though i wont have tasks in this scenario but still nice to know why tasks get null

Comment: In the code you're showing, tasks will never be null. You must be doing something different

Comment: Oh wait. I get it. I suppose `tasks` isn't a thread-safe collection, yet you're adding items concurrently in the `Parallel.ForEach`. If you replace it by a `ConcurrentQueue` for instance, it should fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the regex is really long running there is no need to run the 3 regexes in parallel since your name list is already processed in parallel. So the best solution is to just delete the regex task code.

Simply call the regexes one after the other in sequential code and stop when a match was found. This is fastest and easiest at the same time.

If you want to keep this then note that the TPL cannot cancel your task code for you. The token that you pass is only checked once before running your task code. .NET code is not interruptible. So cancellation cannot possibly work here.

`WhenAll` throwing is indeed a problem that must be mitigated. You can say:

```
Task.WhenAll(myRegexTasks).ContinueWith(_ => { }).Wait();
```

This creates a proxy task whose sole purpose it is to not throw even if the base task throws. Unfortunately, the .NET Framework still has no clean way to wait for a `Task` to complete but not throw.

Comment: `So cancellation cannot possibly work here.` it actually kinda does, otherwise there wouldn't be a TaskCancelledExeption. But it only works because OP is saturating the threadpool, therefore the tasks get a chance to be cancelled before beginning execution.

Comment: @KevinGosse that's true!

Comment: thanks @usr, can you please tell me why wouldnt exception be bubbled up through this proxy method ?

Comment: Because the continuation task executes it's code without throwing.